# Index Error while working with Pandas.pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm having a Problem in pivoting a table. I have the data in a pandas data frame called Rate where i have the user-id, book-id, and rating of that book by that user.

Like this:

```
User  Book  Rating
user1 book1 2.5
user3 book7 3.0
user1 book3 2.0
...   ...   ...
```

and I want to pivot the table with all the unique User as rows, all the unique books as columns and their corresponding rating (3, or 2 or 4.5 whatever) as values. I'm using this line

```
y = Rate.pivot(index=Rate.columns[0], columns=Rate.columns[1], values=Rate.columns[2])
```

But I'm having this error:

```
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-7c13513a221b> in <module>()
      1 #Rate.columns = ['User','Book','Ratings']
----> 2 y = Rate.pivot(index=Rate.columns[0], columns=Rate.columns[1], values=Rate.columns[2])

C:\Users\conne\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   3844         """
   3845         from pandas.core.reshape import pivot
-> 3846         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   3847 
   3848     def stack(self, level=-1, dropna=True):

C:\Users\conne\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
    330         indexed = Series(self[values].values,
    331                          index=MultiIndex.from_arrays([index, self[columns]]))
--> 332         return indexed.unstack(columns)
    333 
    334 

C:\Users\conne\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   2041         """
   2042         from pandas.core.reshape import unstack
-> 2043         return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   2044 
   2045     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\conne\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape.py in unstack(obj, level, fill_value)
    405     else:
    406         unstacker = _Unstacker(obj.values, obj.index, level=level,
--> 407                                fill_value=fill_value)
    408         return unstacker.get_result()
    409 

C:\Users\conne\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape.py in __init__(self, values, index, level, value_columns, fill_value)
     99 
    100         self._make_sorted_values_labels()
--> 101         self._make_selectors()
    102 
    103     def _make_sorted_values_labels(self):

C:\Users\conne\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape.py in _make_selectors(self)
    134         selector = self.sorted_labels[-1] + stride * comp_index + self.lift
    135         mask = np.zeros(np.prod(self.full_shape), dtype=bool)
--> 136         mask.put(selector, True)
    137 
    138         if mask.sum() < len(self.index):

IndexError: index 1495360453 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1495018980"
```

Can someone Please explain me why am receiving the error and how to remove it? Please note that the number of unique user is not equal to the number of unique books!

Comment: It seems you are out of memory [see](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10582#issuecomment-121617815)

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously out of size issue. Assume that you have an array which has size 3 and trying to write 4th inside.

Comment: You mean it's a logical error ? or the Python Memory error that computer doesn't have enough memory ?

Comment: No it's not an event of computer's memory. Thought that you've got an oversized array. Please share your code therefore I can explain you more accurate.